# Removing grub from windows after booting windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, hard-drive, windows-10

I was installing `Ubuntu 20.04.3` on my external hard drive (`sdb`) but by mistake, I installed grub on my internal hard drive (`sda`). Now after realizing my mistake I reinstalled `Ubuntu` with grub on `sdb` and I got successful in booting `ubuntu` from `sdb`. Now the problem is `sda` has `Windows 10` in it, to boot `Windows 10` I need to boot it from `sdb`. I want to remove `grub` so that I can boot `Windows 10` directly from `sda` without connecting `sdb`.

**Note:** I want to do it without any `Windows 10` installation media.

Comment: See launchpad bug 1396379, not your mistake.  Just put the Windows bootloader second, after the USB, so the internal grub never boots. And do add yourself to the bugs's "Does this affect me?" list (in upper left corner), maybe someday it'll be fixed.

Comment: I don't know if this is a mistake or a bug as much as it is a misunderstanding of how UEFI works. There is only supposed to be one EFI partition per device. A workaround would be to disconnect one of the drives when you are installing the other operating system. But then you would need to choose which OS you want to boot using your BIOS/motherboard, since most motherboards will just choose the last EFI booted, making Windows assert itself over GRUB/Ubuntu after you've booted Windows. The best solution IMO is to keep the single EFI on the internal hard drive.